# Get a .pro file from a Makefile

Tags: qt, makefile, qt-creator

I have a project that generates a Makefile by using a custom script.
I would like to import this project into Qt Creator but in a way that I can add new files and compile them automatically (without manually editing the Makefile every time).

To simplify, i need a .pro file that would create a currently available Makefile.
Is there a smarter way to do it but to manually check the dependencies for each source file and add them to the .pro file?

Comment: Hi, interesting question ! I think you can achieve what you want with the custom build step configuration in the Project page. You can create an other custom script which can read your pro file (so your sources) and modify the behavior or your first custom script (Don't know how your first custom script works), to generate your Makefile.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no reliable and full-working way to convert between QMake an CMake. Some tools exist which convert from QMake to CMake but i doubt there is any for CMake to QMake.

Answer (score 0):

```
qmake -project
```

should create the project file. Then use the "Add new file..." from Qt Creator to maintain the .pro file automatically.